# this.props object in console appears different when expanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a container component that is fetching data and passing the props down to its children via re-rendering its own state with the data that is returned from my API call. The issue I am facing resides in the following function:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    console.log(this.props.photos);
    console.log(this.props.photos.allPhotos);
     if (this.props.photos!== prevProps.photos){
         console.log(this.props.photos);
         console.log(this.props.photos.allPhotos);
     }
 }
```

In this screenshot:
[image: non-expanded-object]
I would expect the value of `this.props.photos.allPhotos` to be empty, as it appears to be in the `console.log(this.props.photos.allPhotos)` statement however....

[image]

upon expanding the object within the console, i then see values for all the fields I want to use...

I have no idea why this happens, or how to work around this. Hopefully someone else has come across this before.

Comment: The values of object properties are loaded when you expand it, not at the time of logging. So you are getting the last value, not the initial.